# What Jira role is required so as to have access to Jira import

Tags: user-stories, jira, tools, roles

I am a novice Jira user, part of a pilot project where none of us have notable experience. We are using hosted Jira. The site administrator has made me administrator of a couple of projects. Now I'd like to start by importing a backlog from an existing spreadsheet. I have prepared the CSV, but can nowhere find the "import" link mentioned in the documention, nor can I get to an Administration page such as I am seeing in YouTube videos. I am listed in "users and roles" as an administrator of the project in question, but I am not a site administrator, if that matters.

Comment: Not a direct answer, so will leave it as a comment: you can also use the [Jira API](https://developer.atlassian.com/server/jira/platform/jira-rest-api-examples/) to create Jiras in bulk.

Comment: Good to know, but obviously not useful from the non-admin perspective. (But, something I'll explore more when I move to an organization actively developing with Jira, again.)

Comment: Hi Ari, I haven't read the specific article in detail, but the Jira API is to be used by anyone - don't need any specific admin access.

Answer (score 2):

You need to be a Jira Administrator, per the documentation.

[Cloud](https://confluence.atlassian.com/adminjiracloud/importing-data-from-excel-776636783.html):

> Importing your CSV file
>
> Once your CSV file has been prepared, log into
>   your JIRA Cloud site as a JIRA administrator to start the import
>   process.

[Server](https://confluence.atlassian.com/adminjiraserver071/importing-data-from-csv-802592885.html):

> Running the CSV file import wizard
>
> Before you begin, please back
>   up your JIRA data.
>
> Log in to JIRA as a user with the JIRA
>   Administrators global permission. Select Administration > System >
>   Import & Export > External System Import > Import button associated
>   with the Comma-separated values (CSV) option to open the CSV File
>   import page.

Please note that a Jira Administrator does not grant ALL access, as does Jira System Administrator. You can find more information about the Jira roles in the relevant documentation ([server](https://confluence.atlassian.com/adminjiraserver071/managing-global-permissions-802592439.html), [cloud](https://confluence.atlassian.com/adminjiracloud/managing-global-permissions-776636359.html)).

Comment: That is too bad. The ability to import, rather than use hosted entry tools is a big sanity and time saver. It seems to have been possible in Jira 6 for global-users. I wonder why it was removed.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that Jira =does= allow regular users to import while using the hosted Jira (presumably, 7.x?). This is present as part of the "issues" menu. It is currently absent when beta-testing the new, allegedly improved Jira interface.

So, if the ability to import issues using CSV is important, and you are =not= a Jira administrator, you can do so, but you must be using the current "classic" interface, not beta-testing the new.

This lack may be corrected as the new beta develops.

Comment: The regular-user import mode is a godsend to Jira admins who don't want badly formatted CSVs creating more than just issues. Admin-mode importer can create new values for just about anything in Jira, including new license-eating user accounts.